# Can we have more options in the Closing > Off-Topic > Migration

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, migration

I see a lot of question in StackOverflow that are not suitable (for SO), but could potentially be suitable for a different StackEchange site.

Could we have more options in the `Closing > Off-Topic > Migration` route?

For example CodeReview is not in the list. I think users with a certain rep level should be able to ***vote*** to migrate to *any* other SE site.

Comment: related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79960/when-voting-to-migrate-an-off-topic-question-why-is-the-list-of-sites-limited Robert's answer pretty much explains why this is limited.  If you think something belongs on a different site, then you should use the "Other" flag for the mods explaining why you think it belongs on the other site.

Comment: Emphasis on **explaining why**. Don't just flag "belongs on such and such site" - that's a good way to get ignored.

Comment: @animuson - your comment is not useful in the context of this question (visitors will not know what it means), but it kind of emphasises my point in that a question would not require any moderator attention if the option to migrate to any other site was present. Moderators ignoring flags is not that useful either.

Comment: @Matt It was an extension off of what bluefeet said. We get a lot of crappy migration flags that don't deserve to be acted upon. If you can't explain why, you probably shouldn't be flagging.

Comment: @animuson - believe it or not I have the best interests of SO at heart. I am *trying* to improve an existing alternative to closing a question by providing more options. If you think the migration feature should be removed you could post your own thread on meta to that effect.

Comment: @animuson More and more (good) questions are asked that belongs on Programers or on Code Golf. What should we do then ? According to other meta answers, they SHOULD be flagged when asked on low audience tags. But it takes days for a moderator to migrate them (when it is even done).

Answer (score 13):

About 90 percent of the time, questions aren't of sufficient quality to be migrated anyway.  Close the question, and leave a comment to the OP suggesting that they improve their question and ask it on the new site, after they read their Help Center to make sure that their question is on-topic.

Question migration should be reserved for special cases... really good questions that really need to be on the correct site.  Guidance about "don't cross-post, wait for a migration" is misguided; flagging for migration is too heavyweight for anything except for the special cases.

Comment: Yeah, "delete and repost" is the more sane advice in probably 99% of cases.

Comment: Well we have the migration option now I am just trying to improve it. Several mods have commented on here saying that we shouldn't migrate questions at all so maybe the option should be removed altogether?

Comment: There are still some valid use cases for it.  The problem with targets in the migration list is that users who vote to migrate don't always 1) check the target site scope to make sure that the question is on-topic there, and 2) don't make sure the question is of sufficient quality to warrant migration.  The only thing worse than off-topic questions are questions that are off-topic *twice.*

Comment: What if we change the migration tool? For most people, make that tool just a comment generator - the question is closed and not migrated anywhere, the comment is added that has a link to suggested site. For people who have high reputation on the migration target, a checkbox is added to actually migrate the question (unchecked by default).

Comment: What about the 10% of cases that are good questions that should be migrated?  Just wastes everyone's time having OP delete and repost when it should be easy for one of us to do it with a couple of clicks.