# Stopping Duplicate Question Across Sites?

Tags: discussion

The question is regarding [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350124/) and [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/607089/) by the [same user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3286661/user3286661).

You'll note that the question is an exact copy, as if he just copy pasted the text box into both sites.

Now I'm afraid that eventually the ServerFault guys will flag it to migration to StackOverflow (as they should), and then we'll have duplicate question over here.

Is there a mechanism in place to stop this or what should be done here?

Comment: The second [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/607089/) says: `This question was voluntarily removed by its author`

Comment: Ah, maybe after my comment on that question. Good :)

Comment: There is not really functionality for that beyond what you did. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253869/can-we-have-more-options-in-the-closing-off-topic-migration/253898#comment16342_253898

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/865862/google-cloud-shell-is-temporarily-unavailable

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384646/google-cloud-shell-is-temporarily-unavailable

See these two questions, exact copy across sites.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it would work, some of the more experienced can probably clarify, but the natural thing to do would be to "Mark as Duplicate" the inappropriate one using a link to the appropriate one as the reference.

Can SE mark as duplicate cross site boundaries or should they be able to would be a separate question.

Comment: The thing is once it gets here it will also get marked as duplicate; I think with such obvious duplicates there should be some mechanism to avoid people spamming across sites with the same question ... the _exact_ same question.

Comment: If you feel that a specific user is spamming you maybe should mail team@stackoverflow.com to request that they be blocked.

Comment: Can't mark as duplicate as the question is not in stackoverflow. It says that `the duplicate question should be in stackoverflow` itself.